# How to detect zoom change in flutter leaflet map?

Tags: flutter, leaflet, gesture

How to detect 'zoom in' and 'zoom out' in flutter leaflet map ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) package, in the `MapOptions` there is a `onPositionChanged` callback function. It should return you the zoom details.